# Get file name (with path) from resources

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using camel to create some routes.

I have a file in the resources folder and I only want the file path + name. Not the content.

When I use:

```
from(URI)
 .log("resource:classpath:llave.txt")
```

I got the content of llave.txt but I need something like

> C:\something\llave.txt

Thanks!!

Edit for clarity: I do not need the file information from a **File endpoint** (also, is easy get that info using file language or the exchange's header).

I need the info of a file located in the **resource folder** in the project.

Comment: I doesn't matter. I'm not using it in this case.

Comment: Have you had a look if there is something in the header?

Comment: If URI is using the Camel file component, then various file information is stored as headers, also the relative and absolute path, file size, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Get the file:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("llave.txt").getFile());
```

Get the path:

```
//full path ( including the file ) 
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
// path only
String filePath = absolutePath.
    substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the path using the headers that Camel sets after calling the File component:

```
from(URI)
 .log("$simple{headers.CamelFileAbsolutePath}")
```

You can read more about the File component here:
http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Answer (score 0):

With [java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) you can get the full path:

```
String fullPath = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("llave.txt").toURI()).toString();
```

And the file name:

```
String fileName = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("llave.txt").toURI()).getFileName();
```